# Run a function in a wpf application by autohotkey

Tags: wpf, autohotkey

There is a wpf application. I want to automate a function on that wpf application while its already running. How to do this by autohotkey?

Comment: What you need is AHK Command Picker. See http://blog.danskingdom.com/get-autohotkey-to-interact-with-admin-windows-without-running-ahk-script-as-admin/

Comment: Function means enter some buttons on my application and get the output screen window image. Is it possible?

Comment: i know what a function is investigate the link

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by function. But if you need to automate a gui (press some buttons or other controls, send some input, etc) and after make screeshot, it is possible to do with AutoHotkey. There are commands that allow you to automate gui (which one to use is depent on what you need to do). For making screenshot look here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91585-screen-capture-using-only-ahk-no-3rd-party-software-required/